# msql wrong total and sum on result

Tags: mysql

We have three different following tables...

**users**

id,
username
password
email

**user_clubs**

id,
user_id,
club_name

**sales**

id,
club_id,
amount,
admin_fees,
dnt

And we want to get total sum of admin_fees as outstanding for user_id(for example 55), so we tried following...

```
SELECT u.id, count(c.id), SUM(s.admin_fees) as total_admin_fees 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_clubs c ON c.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.club_id = c.id
WHERE u.id = 55
GROUP BY u.id;
```

But its returning value of first row, so balance is not correct, Please help to resolve.

Comment: You should consider uploading your scheme to http://www.sqlfiddle.com so we can check it out.

Comment: ok i will use sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT   g.id, count(g.club_id), SUM(g.admin_fees) AS total_admin_fees 
FROM     (
            SELECT    u.id, c.id AS club_id, s.admin_fees
            FROM      users u
            LEFT JOIN user_clubs c ON c.user_id = u.id
            LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.club_id = c.id
            WHERE     u.id = 55
         ) AS g
GROUP BY g.id;
```